# Javascript infinite prototype chain

Tags: javascript, prototype, firebug

I am using the following test code:

```
function Test() {

 }

 Test.prototype.MyMethod =  {
    a: function() {

    },
    b: function() {

    }
 }
```

And to run it I'm simply doing:

```
var test = new Test();
console.debug(test);
```

In the firebug console, I expand the object that was printed and look inside of `__proto__`:

In there find a seemingly unending chain of constructor -> prototype:

```
+MyMethod
-constructor
  -prototype
     +MyMethod
     -constructor
        -prototype
           +MyMethod
           -constructor
```

and so on.  Did I do something wrong here?  Why does the prototype chain seem unending?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`prototype`s have a property called `constructor` that refers to the function that owns the prototype.

This cycle is by design.

Comment: Well, he didn't assigned '`prototype` to an object', if you look carefully, he just created a property named `MyMethod`: `Test.prototype.MyMethod = {/*...*/};`. So `test.constructor` points back to the `Test` function.

Answer (score 9):

The prototype's constructor refers back to itself, so as you 'unfold' it, you are just opening the same structure over and over again. It is not actually 'infinite.'