# Infinite prototype chain

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why in this code:

```
var originalfunc = function() {
    this.run(this)
};

originalfunc.prototype.run = function(basefunc) {
    this.basefunc = basefunc;
    console.log(this);
};

var r = new originalfunc();
```

Produces a prototype chain that looks to be infinite:

[image]

Why is this happening? I know I'm assigning the originalfunc obj as a property of the run prototype but I'm only doing that once.

Working fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YmThL/

Comment: You are calling run and passing `this` as a parameter.  Then you are setting `this.basefunc` to that.  So, `this.basefunc` *is* `originalfunc` which has a `basefunc` property which is `originalfunc` which has a `basefunc` property which is `originalfunc`...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're setting `this.basefunc` to be a reference to the object referenced by `this`.

The constructor calls "run", passing the value `this` to it. At that point, `this` refers to the new object under construction. The "run" function sets the "basefunc" property on that same object (because `this` will also refer to it inside that call to "run") to the parameter, which was the object.

The effect is the same as if the constructor simply did:

```
this.basefunc = this;
```

Comment: Indeed, this is just a reference to itself. Nothing to do with a prototype.

Comment: An interesting question might be why Chrome doesn't figure that out.

Comment: Ok, I get that it's a reference but does that mean I have some sort of infinite loop here that's eating up memory?

Comment: I think this is the answer to my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740849/javascript-infinite-prototype-chain?rq=1

Comment: @MikeRifgin no - the loop is in the Chrome console code that lets you "open up" your object.  Just having a self-referential object property isn't necessarily harmful.